# A Cisco AnyConnect VPN alternative for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, vpn

Is it possible to use OpenConnect or some other VPN alternative on macOS? Has anyone done this successfully?

The only software I've been able to find saying it is possible is http://www.feingeist.io/shimo/ which costs €50 :-o

Comment: Mac OS X has a built in VPN, you may be able to use that, but it depends on the VPN server you're connecting to. If the server you're connecting to only does AnyConnect VPNs, then you're stuck with that.

Comment: FYI, I was able to install/use my old version of AnyConnect. Also, the latest version does officially support El Capitan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenConnect works great on El Capitan. I use the text commands to connect to my work VPN.

There's a Gist with a walkthrough of setup instructions using the Homebrew installer: https://gist.github.com/moklett/3170636

On El Capitan, the "rootless" protection prevents you from installing the unauthorized "tun tap" kernel driver extension that OpenConnect needs.

However, a Mac app called Viscosity comes with a signed (authorized) copy of tun tap. Viscosity has a limited trial, but the driver is free. https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/

Install Viscosity and run the app once to get the helper (driver) installed. Then use OpenConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for Cisco anyconnect on MacOS Mojave is [Shimo VPN](https://www.shimovpn.com/). A bit pricey, but it works well with cisco VPN.